# Android dynamically add custom component to LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i want add a custom component on a LinearLayout whenever i touch a button.

This is my code:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_cartelle_immagini);

View custom = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_folder, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.label_pathFolder);
textView.setText(pathDirectory);

Spinner spinnerLevel = (Spinner) custom.findViewById(R.id.spinner_level);

try{

root.addView(custom);
}catch(Throwable e) {
    Log.e("BurgerClub", "MEX: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this way, only first custom component is added, why?

Thanks

**edit:**
I've modified my code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
((ViewGroup) root).addView(custom, myCount, params);
```

This is my custom component:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    style="@style/Theme.BurgerClubStyle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_pathFolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        style="@style/customText" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_level"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_show_desc_img"
        android:entries="@array/n_level_array"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:prompt="@string/n_level_prompt"
        android:textAlignment="3"
        style="@style/customText" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_desc_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_remove_folder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_press"
        android:contentDescription="@string/showDescImg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_desc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_remove_folder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_press"
        android:contentDescription="@string/showDescImg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first time that i press the button, custom component was added, but all other times NOT.
The first custom element is not overwrite, it's the only visible!

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are facing a little better? What do you mean with "only the first component is added" ?

Comment: you add more but they overlap.. use layout params and rules to make new one appear below the other one, there are quesiton and answers try googling

Comment: Verify orientation of your layout

Comment: The code that i've posted is inside a function that is called whenever a specify button is pressed. The first time that i press button the custom component is added but all other times NOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your layout_cartelle_immagini declared?

Probably it's a horizontal LinearLayout, just set orientation to vertical and your code should work (considering the code to add a custom view is inside a onClickListener).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will help you.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
root.addContentView(custom, params);
```

Comment: @Sajmon I tried your code but i've the same problem, Have i to remove components inside view and reinsert all whenever i added new custom component?

Comment: @PapaSmurf its not my code i just edited answer. you ned to provide more information.